# batch script to execute a terminal command

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing

Am new to bacth scripting
am trying to execute following terminal command using batch file

```
"C:\Program Files\dark\dark" -z "lip" -Z doc > sample.doc
```

the following command outputs some data as sample doc.

while i running the batch file 
am getting the command as  `"C:\Program Files\dark\dark" -z "lip" -Z doc 1>sample.doc`

1 is appending in front of  `>` sign.
Is there any way to avoid this?

Answer (score 1):

There is a set of data streams associated with each console session / command / batch script, and each stream has a number: `0 = stdin`, `1 = stdout`, `2 = stderr`. The standard output stream is number 1, so

```
command > file  ==  command 1> file
```

both commands are equivalent, meaning: *"execute the command and redirect the `stdout` stream of the command to the file"*. The second one is just more explicit, and is what you see when `echo` is not disabled and the batch parser dumps the command that will be executed. You can also try writing it as

```
>file command
```

and the resulting command echoed to console will be the same. The parser does its work and echoes the resulting command.

So, you can see the command or hide it with

```
@command > file
```

or

```
@echo off
command > file
```

but the command executed will be the same.